# Issue with multiple files in Cloudinary's upload widget v2

Tags: angular, cloudinary

Scenario #1: I have set `multiple: false` in one component. When I tried to upload a file, it opens a popup for selecting a file. I can't select multiple files by pressing the control button as well - working fine.

Scenario #2: I have set `multiple: true` in the second component. When I tried to upload a file, it opens a popup for selecting files. I can select multiple files by pressing the control button - working fine.

The problem occurs here in scenario #3:

I navigate to the first component after multiple files uploaded, but though it is set with `multiple: false`, I can select multiple files with the control button but only upload one image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to share a sample code? I created one in my CodeSandBox environment and it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/cloudinary-upload-widget-multiple-fcmrh. When using the widget with `multiple:false`, I can only select 1 image even after using the widget with `multiple:true`